# kdev-ruby's CMakeFile.txt requires weird stuff like KF5Config.cmake

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

I'm trying to compile a Ruby plugin for KDevelop: https://github.com/KDE/kdev-ruby

When I cut a folder called `build`, `cd build`, and run `cmake ..`, I get lots of errors:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (include):
include could not find load file:

    KDEInstallDirs


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (include):
include could not find load file:

    KDECMakeSettings


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (include):
include could not find load file:

    KDECompilerSettings


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (include):
include could not find load file:

    ECMQtDeclareLoggingCategory


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
By not providing "FindKF5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "KF5", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5" (requested
version 5.15.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5Config.cmake
    kf5-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "KF5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "KF5_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "KF5" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

How, on Ubuntu, do I install something that provides `KF5Config.cmake`? Preferably without rebuilding KDevelop or KDE or Qt5.

Comment: I guess you need [Extra CMake Modules](https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules) package to be installed. It is strange that you haven't it, as `find_package(ECM ...)` at [line 9](https://github.com/KDE/kdev-ruby/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L9) haven't emit any error.

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop relies on the development headers for various libraries, and finds them via the accompanying CMake files.

The build also uses CMake modules provided by the `extra-cmake-modules` package.

You must install that and `libkf5config-dev`.

The [apt-file](http://.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/apt-file.1.html) command might help you find the relevant packages for your distro in these situations.

Comment: I already have `extra-cmake-modules`, and `libkf5config-dev`. None of them came with any `KF5Config.cmake`.

Comment: @Philip: Which files `extra-cmake-modules` package contains in your distro? Only `ECMConfig.cmake` one? You may find which package contains `FindKF5.cmake` file (exactly this file is part of *Extra CMake Modules*, not a `KF5Config.cmake` one).